# How can I change my code to prevent 'Cannot convert string to float' errors?

Tags: python, string, numpy

I'm writing a piece of code to analyse the output from a lab instrument, and though it's in a text file, the data seems to be stored weirdly.  I've loaded it in and used the split function to get it into a np array, but it's refusing to convert the number strings to floats, and I can't understand why.  I think it might be the encoding, as when I print the strings, they give lots of slashes and zeroes that shouldn't be there.
My code:

```
import numpy as np
x = open("G008a.txt", 'r')
data = x.read()

with open("G008.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
good_lines = []
for i in range(len(lines)-1):
    if len(lines[i]) > 0:
        if lines[i][1].isdigit():
            good_lines.append(lines[i])
numerical_data = []
for i in range(len(good_lines)):
    numerical_data.append(good_lines[i].split())
data = np.array(numerical_data).astype(float)
temp = data[:,1]
heat_flow = data[:,5]
```

My data:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G4OluNk6yiTIkNvvf4gEe2npKzME88ak/view?usp=drivesdk

The result:
[image: error]

Comment: Could you include the stack trace that gets thrown?

Comment: the code works fine, I did not get any error

Comment: Have added the stack trace, and edited so it throws the error (I accidentally deleted that bit when troubleshooting).  The aim of the code is to end with an array of numbers, rather than floats

Comment: If you don't want `floats`, why are you using `astype(float)`?  But what do you mean by numbers?  floats are numbers.  That said, your problem is that `numerical_data` appears to be a list of bytestrings.  You need to look more at `good_lines[i].split()`, and the file read, to make sure it produces text that can be converted to numbers.

Comment: I meant floats instead of strings, not numbers instead of floats, sorry

Comment: Looks like your lines after 'start data' would load nicely with `np.genfromtxt`.

Comment: I've tried np.genfromtxt and it didn't work, just gave an array of nans
(using data2 = np.genfromtxt('G008.txt', skip_header = 120))

Answer (score 0):

Solved, used np.genfromtxt, the key was to use encoding UTF-16